# How to save and load a Peft/LoRA Finetune (star-chat)

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, torch

I am trying to further finetune `Starchat-Beta`, save my progress, load my progress, and continue training. But whatever I do, it doesn't come together. Whenever I load my progress and continue training, my loss starts back from *zero* (3.xxx in my case).
I'll run you through my code and then the problem.

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(BASEPATH)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "/notebooks/starbaseplus"
    ...
)
# I get both the Tokenizer and the Foundation model from the starbaseplus repo (which I have locally). 

peftconfig = LoraConfig(
    "/notebooks/starchat-beta" 
    base_model_name_or_path = "/notebooks/starbaseplus",
    ...
)
model = get_peft_model(model, peftconfig)
# All Gucci so far, the model and the LoRA fine-tune are loaded from the starchat-beta repo (also local).

# important for later:
print_trainable_parameters(model)
# trainable params: 306 Million || all params: 15 Billion || trainable: 1.971%


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    ...
)
trainer.train()
# I train, loss drops. from 3.xx to 1.xx.

# Now, either I follow the HugginFace docks:
model.save_pretrained("./huggingface_model") 
# -> saves /notebooks/huggingface_model/adapter_model.bin 16mb.

# or an alternative I found on SO:
trainer.save_model("./torch_model") 
# -> saves /notebooks/torch_model/pytorch_model.bin 60gb.
```

I have two alternatives saved to disk. Lets restart and try either of these approaches

First the [huggingface docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/quicktour#peftmodel) approach:
I now have three sets of weights.

1. the foundation model - starbase plus
2. the chat finetune - starchat-beta
3. the 16mb saved bin - adapter_model.bin

But I only have two opportunities to load weights.

1. `AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained`
2. either `get_peft_model` or `PeftModel.from_pretrained`

Neither works. training restarts at a loss of 3.x.

Second approach:
Load the 60bg instead of the *old* starchat-beta repo model.
`get_peft_model("/notebooks/torch_model/pytorch_model.bin", peftconfig)`

Also doesn't work. The `print_trainable_parameters(model)` drops to `trainable: 0.02%` and training restarts at a loss of 3.x

Comment: Use huggingface hub to push your finetune lora model

Comment: @Hemanthkumar I want to keep it local for now. Pushing comes later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the the `save_pretrained` and `from_pretrained` from HF were broken for a time. they fixed it with the newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **is_trainable=True** next time you load the model and adapter

```
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(
    model,
    "local/myAdapter/adapter_config.json",
    is_trainable=True
)
model.eval()
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your knowledgable answer. I have added code formatting — you can do that by surrounding the code with triple backticks \`\`\`...\`\`\`